# Surface Pro magnetic connectors next to laptop

Tags: hardware-failure, microsoft-surface

I have seen questions about magnets and damage to laptops, but they were about weaker magnets like headsets and mobile phones.

I normally place my laptop in a backpack when I travel.

I recently bought a `Surface Pro`; if I place the `Surface Pro` next to my laptop in the backpack, is there a chance of the magnetic connectors on the `Surface Pro` damaging my laptop hard disks?  (not necessarily erase, but just flipping a few bits would be enough to damage it)

Comment: I've been carrying my Surface in close proximity with USB sticks/HDDs, SD cards etc. (even had an SSD in the bag for a few days). No problems yet as far as I can see.

Comment: @Karan, I'm more worried about the magnetic connectors affecting the hard disks in my laptop (not sure if they affect USB sticks and / or SD/SSD drives!)

Comment: Well my USB HDD wasn't affected, so I don't see why your laptop HDD would be any different. IMO there should be sufficient shielding in place to prevent your laptop HDD from getting affected or wiped by the tablet's magnetic connectors.

Comment: @Karan Thanks, I'm reassured by your comments!